# TouchGFX for STM32H745XI

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, touchscreen, stm32h7, touchgfx

my project requires me to use STM32H745, and i also need to use the touch screen panel as there is a need for GUI.

I searched for stm32h745 touchgfx, but there are no results for it, some even say that there is no touchgfx support for stm32h745, is it true that there is no support for h745?

How do I find if there is a support and why is everyone only using stm32h750 for touchgfx examples and tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

I made the custom board across H745xit6 core board.
the board I purchased on Aliexpress.
After spending few nights , my touchGFX is working fine on internal memory.
Struggling now for external loader (MT25QL256A) to store the gfx images.

regards

Imran

[my custom designed board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ8RA.jpg)

Comment: following is the H745xit6 core board link on Aliexpress

https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005003648568813.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2vnm